# Child actor's scheduler is not stopped and throws a NPE after stopping parent actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

**Flow:**

- I have 3 levels of actors (`A`, `B`and `C`).
- `A` creates `B`, and `B` creates `C`. `A --> B --> C`
- `B` and `C` have 2 states: `working` and `ending`. After `C` finishes all the stuff, it enters to the `ending` state where it starts a scheduler to send a `CFinished` message to `B`.
- When `B` receives the `CFinished` message also enters to its `ending` state and it starts its own scheduler to send a `BFinished` message to `A`
- When `A` receives the `BFinished` message, also enters to an `ending` state and calls a `context stop self`, stopping itself and all the children he created.

**Problem:**

It looks like the schedulers don't stop after the actor has been stopped, and the next time they are fired, they throw a `NullPointerException`.

How could I solve this?

**Code:**

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, Cancellable, Props}
import com.zinio.damntool.msg.{BFinished, CFinished}


object msg {
  case class BFinished()
  case class CFinished()
}

object A {
  def props(): Props = Props(new A())
}

class A() extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  implicit val ec = context.dispatcher

  context actorOf B.props

  def receive = working

  def working: Receive = {
    case BFinished =>
      log.warning("[Actor B] -> Received: BFinished")
      context stop self
  }
}

object B {
  def props(): Props = Props(new B())
}

class B() extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  implicit val ec = context.dispatcher
  var cancellable: Cancellable = _

  context actorOf C.props

  def receive = working

  def working: Receive = {
    case CFinished =>
      log.warning("[Actor B] -> Received: CFinished")
      cancellable = scheduleEndActor
      context become ending
  }

  def ending: Receive = {
    case _ =>
  }

  def scheduleEndActor = context.system.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 5.seconds)(endActor())

  def endActor() = context.parent ! BFinished
}

object C {
  def props(): Props = Props(new C())
}

class C() extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  implicit val ec = context.dispatcher
  var cancellable: Cancellable = _

  self ! CFinished

  def receive = working

  def working: Receive = {
    case CFinished =>
      log.warning("[Actor C] -> Received: CFinished")
      cancellable = scheduleEndActor
      context become ending
  }

  def ending: Receive = {
    case _ =>
  }

  def scheduleEndActor = context.system.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 5.seconds)(endActor())

  def endActor() = context.parent ! CFinished
}
```

**Error:**

```
[WARN] [10/20/2016 00:05:59.700] [test-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://test-system/user/$a/$a/$a] [Actor C] -> Received: CFinished
[WARN] [10/20/2016 00:05:59.706] [test-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://test-system/user/$a/$a] [Actor B] -> Received: CFinished
[WARN] [10/20/2016 00:05:59.709] [test-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://test-system/user/$a] [Actor B] -> Received: BFinished
[ERROR] [10/20/2016 00:06:04.714] [test-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [TaskInvocation] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.B.endActor(Test.scala:62)
    at com.test.B$$anonfun$scheduleEndActor$1.apply$mcV$sp(Test.scala:60)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$2.run(Scheduler.scala:78)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$2$$anon$1.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:104)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:409)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

[ERROR] [10/20/2016 00:06:04.714] [test-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [TaskInvocation] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.C.endActor(Test.scala:90)
    at com.test.C$$anonfun$scheduleEndActor$2.apply$mcV$sp(Test.scala:88)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$2.run(Scheduler.scala:78)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$2$$anon$1.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:104)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:409)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: Can you post how ``B`` and ``C`` schedule their message?

Comment: Shouldn't be an NPE, just dead letter office - how are you sending the messages?

Comment: I have edited the question with a real example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just realised that I can stop the schedulers overriding the `postStop` method. This way, the `NullPointerException` is not thrown.

```
  override def postStop(): Unit = cancellable.cancel
```

Answer (score 2):

First: Why you need a scheduler if initial delay is zero?
Second: If you really need it, then you could use the `context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(x.seconds, context.parent, BFinished )`. In that way you not need to use the `cancellable.cancel` at all.

Comment: Message delivery is not guaranteed on Akka. Of course there are simpler and more complicated scenarios, but you should never rely on the assumption that one message will be delivered correctly. For more information: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.11/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#discussion-why-no-guaranteed-delivery

Answer (score 2):

It throws a NPE because you're accessing `context.parent` from another thread.

use

```
def scheduleEndActor = context.system.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 5.seconds, context.parent, BFinished)
```

Comment: I see that it doesn't throw the NPE this way. But, is the scheduler cancelled? I wouldn't like to have schedulers alive for already stopped actors.

Comment: cancel the task in postStop.